# Kotlin Retrofit Error "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT"

Tags: android, json, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I've read through multiple posts on StackOverflow, but haven't found a solution that fits my problem yet. Could you please help me fix this Retrofit error?

JSON response:

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "barcode_number": "8000040000802",
        "barcode_type": "EAN",
        "barcode_formats": "EAN 8000040000802",
        "mpn": "",
        "model": "",
        "asin": "",
        "product_name": "Campari Bitter 25% Vol. 1 L",
        "title": "",
        "category": "Food, Beverages & Tobacco > Beverages > Alcoholic Beverages > Bitters",
        "manufacturer": "Campari",
        "brand": "Campari",
        "label": "",
        "author": "",
        "publisher": "",
        "artist": "",
        "actor": "",
        "director": "",
        "studio": "",
        "genre": "",
        "audience_rating": "",
        "ingredients": "",
        "nutrition_facts": "",
        "color": "",
        "format": "",
        "package_quantity": "",
        "size": "",
        "length": "",
        "width": "",
        "height": "",
        "weight": "",
        "release_date": "",
        "description": "",
        "features": [],
        "images": [
            "https://images.barcodelookup.com/19631/196313718-1.jpg"
        ],
        "stores": [
            {
                "store_name": "Rakuten Deutschland GmbH",
                "store_price": "16.50",
                "product_url": "https://www.rakuten.de/produkt/campari-bitter-25-vol-1-l-1826679605",
                "currency_code": "EUR",
                "currency_symbol": "€"
            }
        ],
        "reviews": []
    }
]
}
```

Data classes that have been created by the JSON to Kotlin plugin:

```
data class BaseResponse(
   val products: List<Product>
)
```

Product:

```
data class Product(
    val actor: String,
    val artist: String,
    val asin: String,
    val audience_rating: String,
    ...
)
```

Store:

```
data class Store(
    val currency_code: String,
    val currency_symbol: String,
    val product_url: String,
    val store_name: String,
    val store_price: String
)
```

Service:

```
interface BarcodeLookupApiService {
    @GET("products")
    suspend fun getArticleData(@Query("barcode") barcode: String,
                               @Query("key") key: String): List<BaseResponse>
}
```

Retrofit Builder:

```
object RetrofitBuilder {
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/"

    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    val apiService: BarcodeLookupApiService =
        getRetrofit().create(BarcodeLookupApiService::class.java)
}
```

Are the data classes created by the plugin not right? Or should my service not return a list? I've tried returning a simple BaseResponse object but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your interface as shown below:

```
interface BarcodeLookupApiService {
    @GET("products")
    suspend fun getArticleData(@Query("barcode") barcode: String,
                               @Query("key") key: String): BaseResponse
}
```

and to get list of products do as shown below:

```
baseRespose.ProductsList
```

This will fix your issue. The response is an object with has an array inside object. Hence you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Laravel framework to build my web service or Rest Api with Sanctum. Ok the problem was here:

```
{
    "result": {
        "message": "Registrado correctamente",
        "success": true,
        "status": 200,
        "error": null
    }
}
```

The GsonConverter queries of `brackets` yes look here be careful:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "message": "Registrado correctamente",
            "success": true,
            "status": 200,
            "error": null
        }
    ]
```

I update my backend Api:

```
   $result = [
            'message' => 'Registrado correctamente',
            'success' => true,
            'status' => 200,
            'error' => null         
           ];
         
           return response()->json([
               'result' => $result,
           ], 200);
```

to

```
  return response()->json([
               'result' => [$result],
           ], 200);
```

See careful I have added brackets `[ ]` to 'result'. This fixed my problem.

My two data class were this:

```
@Parcelize
data class RegisterResponseObj(
    val message: String,
    val success: Boolean,
    val status: Int = -1,
    val error: String?,
) : Parcelable

data class RegisterResponse(val result: List<RegisterResponseObj>)
```

The web service:

```
interface WebService {
        
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @POST("register")
    suspend fun registerUser(@Field("name") name: String,
                            @Field("email") email: String,
                            @Field("password")password: String): RegisterResponse

}
```

Cheers!